# IL comments with cecil

Tags: cil, mono.cecil

Is it possible using mono Cecil to get and set IL comments? I'm trying to add a comment to an assembly using a patcher, so that if the patcher gets run on the file twice it can access the comment and avoid making changes twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not add comments to the methodbody.

But you can persist your information in the metadata by adding them as custom attributes on the first run. When you need complex data it could be a bit tricky since [types in custom attributes are limited to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664615(v=vs.71).aspx):

> - One of the following types: bool, byte, char, double, float, int,    long, short, string.
> - The type object.
> - The type System.Type.
> - An enum type, provided it has public accessibility and the types in    which it is nested (if any) also have public accessibility (Section
>     17.2).
> - Single-dimensional arrays of the above types.

But when you are a bit creative it should be doable, for example when its enough to mark offsets in the methodbody after a change you could add metadata like this:

```
public class C
{
    [TypeOneChanges(new uint[] { 0, 16, 124 })]
    [TypeTwoChanges(new uint[] { 5, 10 })]
    public void M() { }
}

[AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Method)]
class RemarkableOffsetAttribute : Attribute
{
    public uint[] Offsets { get; }

    public RemarkableOffsetAttribute(uint[] offsets)
    {
        Offsets = offsets;
    }
}

class TypeOneChangesAttribute : RemarkableOffsetAttribute
{
    public TypeOneChangesAttribute(uint[] offsets) : base(offsets) { }
}

class TypeTwoChangesAttribute : RemarkableOffsetAttribute
{
    public TypeTwoChangesAttribute(uint[] offsets) : base(offsets) { }
}
```